# jQuery datepicker not working properly when used in AJAX form

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have used jQuery DatePicker on a website and it works perfectly with all the options that I used.

However, whenever the form is put into an AJAX pop-up window the DatePicker still appears and I can pop up the calendar bu selecting dates is not possible. When I click on the date it breaks and does not do anything - sometimes closes without updating the field, sometimes the calendar just stays there.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide an example of the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Thank you for your reply: here is a link to the problem:
    http://www.realadventures.com/php/test.htm

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the datepicker in the popup window:

```
var dates2 = $( "#checkIn_date2, #checkOut_date2" ).datepicker({ /* ... */ });
```

before the popup (and hence `#checkIn_date2` and `#checkOut_date2`) exist. The popup window doesn't exist until you click the "popup inquiry" link and binding to something that doesn't exist doesn't do anything useful. You should bind the datepickers in the popup **after** the popup has been created.